# TimePicker with 24 hour format

Tags: jquery, timepicker

I using timepicker in my project but I need this time in 24 hour without am,pm 
this is my code

```html
<div class="bootstrap-timepicker" >
<label for="email" class="col-sm-2 control-label">From Time</label>
<input type="text" id="from_time" class="form-control timepicker" style="width: 30%;" >
<label for="email" class="col-sm-2 control-label">To Time</label>
<input type="text" id="to_time" class="form-control timepicker" style="width: 30%;" >
<!-- /.input group -->
</div>
```

but this code give me 12 hour format like this

```
04:00 PM
```

but what I want

```
16:00
```

Comment: snippet you provided is not working

Comment: What you have tried ? you need to update JS function / change function attribute for change time format

Comment: could you please confirm datepicker you are using is jquery datepicker or bootstrap ?

Comment: bootstrap-timepicker.min.js this javascript file which I used that mean it bootstrap

Answer (score 5):

if you are using jquery timepicker

`$('input.timepicker').timepicker({
    timeFormat: 'HH:mm:ss',
});`

if you are using bootstrap timepicker

```
$(function () {
    $('#datetimepicker4').datetimepicker({
        pickDate: false,
        minuteStepping:30,
        format: 'hh:mm',
        pickTime: true,
        defaultDate: new Date(1979, 0, 1, 8, 0, 0, 0),
        language:'en',
        use24hours: true
    });
});
```

Answer (score 3):

if you are using the bootstrap

```
$('.time-picker').timepicker({
        showMeridian: false     
    });
```

OR you can try this one as well, not tested:

```
  $('input.timepicker').timepicker({ timeFormat: 'HH:mm:ss p' });
```

Hope this helps you. 
Enjoy

Comment: thank u for your  reply but I using timepicker not datetimepicker

Comment: show meridian works thank you just what i needed

Answer (score 2):

For the jQuery timepicker you need to use the 'timeFormat' option with PHP's date() formatting syntax:

```
$('.time').timepicker({
  'timeFormat': 'H:i'
});
```

Documentation: https://github.com/jonthornton/jquery-timepicker#timepicker-plugin-for-jquery

Answer (score 2):

You can use this to get 24-hour format:

```
$('input.timepicker').timepicker({
timeFormat: 'h:i',});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this

```
$('.timepicker').timepicker({
    disableMousewheel: true,
    icons: {
        up: 'la la-angle-up',
        down: 'la la-angle-down'
    },
    showSeconds: true,
    showMeridian: false,
    defaultTime: new Date()
}).on('changeTime.timepicker', function (e) {

    var hours = ('0' + e.time.hours).slice(-2);
    var minutes = ('0' + e.time.minutes).slice(-2);
    var seconds = ('0' + e.time.seconds).slice(-2);

    $(this).val(hours + ':' + minutes + ':' + seconds);
});
```

Comment: Please put your answer always in context instead of just pasting code. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) for more details.

Comment: there is perhaps not enough context but it's the most usefull answer of the thread, all other "solutions" give me "0:00"

Answer (score 1):

This works for me.

`$('input[name="entry_deadline_time"]').daterangepicker({
    singleDatePicker: true,
    showDropdowns: false,
    timePicker: true,
    timeFormat: 'HH:mm:ss p',
    locale: {
        format: 'MM-DD-YYYY HH:mm:ss'
    }
});`

Answer (score 0):

You could use `type:"time"`.

```
<div class="bootstrap-timepicker" >
  <label for="email" class="col-sm-2 control-label">From Time</label>
  <input type="time" id="from_time" class="form-control timepicker" style="width: 30%;" >
  <label for="email" class="col-sm-2 control-label">To Time</label>
  <input type="time" id="to_time" class="form-control timepicker" style="width: 30%;" >
  <!-- /.input group -->
</div>
```

Note that this doesn't work in FireFox.

> Firefox's time control is very similar to Chrome's, except that it doesn't have the up and down arrows and it is a 12 hour clock (with an additional slot to specify AM or PM).

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code

```
<html>
<head> ... </head>
<body>
...
<form ... >
...
<input type="text" class="timepicker" name="timepicker" />
...
</form>
...
</body>

<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/timepicker/1.3.5/jquery.timepicker.min.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/timepicker/1.3.5/jquery.timepicker.min.css">

<script type="text/javascript">
       $(document).ready(function() {
         $('.timepicker').timepicker({
                timeFormat: 'HH:mm',
                interval: 60,
                defaultTime: '10',
              });
       });
     </script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

This is how I have added the time field.

```
<input id="timepicker3" type="text" class="form-control event-time-from" name="event-time-from" value="10:30 AM" data-provide="timepicker" placeholder="HH:MM" required>
```

This is what makes it accept time in 24-hour format.

```
$(".event-time-from").timepicker({ showMeridian: !1});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code:

```
<html>
<head> ... </head>
<body>
  ...
  <form>
    <input type="text" class="timepicker" name="timepicker" />
  </form>
</body>

<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/timepicker/1.3.5/jquery.timepicker.min.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/timepicker/1.3.5/jquery.timepicker.min.css">

<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('.timepicker').timepicker({
      timeFormat: 'HH:mm',
      dropdown: true,
      scrollbar: true
      use24hours: true,
      interval: 60 
    });
  });
</script>
</html>
```

Comment: Hello, please don't just submit code in your answer(s), add some details as to why you think this is the optimal solution.